# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'retrofit2.Response' is not a valid response body type. Did you mean ResponseBody?

Tags: android, retrofit2

My question is so similar to [Retrofit 2.0 beta 4 response get IllegalArgumentException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35602521/513413) but its answer didn't help me.

I'm migrating from Retrofit 1.9 to 2.0.2.
I'm registering my app for messaging once launches.

```
    /**
     * Synchronous method to register GCM Token on Backend Server
     *
     * @return true, in case of success response, false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean registerGCMToken()
    {
        ...

        try
        {
            Call<Response> call = mService.registerGCMToken(sessionId, this.ADDITIONAL_QUERY);
            final Response response = call.execute().body(); // <<< Error points here
            final DefaultResponse defaultResponse = DefaultResponse.newInstance(response);
            return defaultResponse.isSuccess();
        }
        catch (IOException ignored)
        {

        }

        return false;
    }
```

My interface looks like:

```
    @GET("my/url")
    Call<Response> registerGCMToken(@Header(Constant.HEADER_WILDCARD) String accessToken,
                    @QueryMap Map<String, String> additionalQuery);
```

Once I launch the app I'm getting this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'retrofit2.Response' is not a
>   valid response body type. Did you mean ResponseBody?

and points to the line I mentioned above.

My newInstance method looks like:

```
    public static final DefaultResponse newInstance(final Response response)
    {
        final DefaultResponse defaultResponse = new DefaultResponse();
        if (response != null)
        {
            defaultResponse.status = response.code();
        }

        return defaultResponse;
    }
```

So as you see, I need to know what is the HTTP status code. By changing `Response` generic to `ResponseBody` I'm not able to get http status code. What is your recommendation?

Answer (score 7):

What i got while reading answers from the post suggested by you is that instead of this :

```
@GET("my/url")
    Call<Response> registerGCMToken(@Header(Constant.HEADER_WILDCARD) String accessToken,
                    @QueryMap Map<String, String> additionalQuery);
```

Try :

```
@GET("my/url")
    Call<ResponseBody> registerGCMToken(@Header(Constant.HEADER_WILDCARD) String accessToken,
                    @QueryMap Map<String, String> additionalQuery);
```

Because you are getting ResponseBody and not Response here :

```
        final Response response = call.execute().body();
```

Like he did : [How can I handle empty response body with Retrofit 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33228126/how-can-i-handle-empty-response-body-with-retrofit-2/33228322#33228322)

Comment: Thanks Sharad, I actually tested that and the problem is I cannot get HTTP status code from `ResponseBody`. However, if I call the API, Its interface has a method, public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {...}, that I'm able to get status code from `response`. This is confusing me that how can I get Response in synchronous way.

Comment: @Hesam I have not much idea about that, and ofcourse not more than you. You may check it for synchronous way : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36425488/how-to-get-http-response-status-in-synchronous-retrofit-2
and this for HTTP code : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33774940/get-response-status-code-using-retrofit-2-0-and-rxjava

Comment: thanks bro, in asynchronous way I have no problem to get it as Response class works fine, same as your docs.

Comment: I am having he same issue. I want to make a synchronous call, and I just want the response status. I don't care about the body.